# Template type array of varadic template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-functions

I am creating a library for myself that contains functions and macros for things I use often and don't want to constantly retype or copy/paste (sometimes hundreds of lines long). I have a chunk of code in an old project that I have to copy and paste constantly and then change all the variable names to fit my current project. I want to turn the chunk of code into a function in my library.

The big chuck of code formats output into a box so if the output is too long it doesn't ruin any borders I may have or go right to the edge of the console (which bothers me). The user passes the top-left corner of the box and provides the x coordinate of the right edge that the text should not pass. The rest of the arguments are the variables or literals to be outputted. The chunk of code puts all the variables and literals into one big string which is then outputted char by char until the output reaches the x boundary. The output then continues at the x coord of the top-left corner and one line down.

In order for this to work the function must have a varadic template to allow for variable amounts of multiple types of output (similar to `cout << "I have " << 4.5 << " cookies and " << 2 << " friends."`).

The template is complete and works until I try to create an array of the template type and initialize it.

```
template<typename ...Inputs>
void textBox(int x, int y, int xBoundary, const Inputs&... things) {
    Inputs arr[sizeof...(things)] = {things...};
}
```

At this point I get this error: `parameter packs not expanded with '...' Note: 'Inputs'`

I have used this type of thing before but all the inputs were of the same type for that function so I could easily just do this:

```
template<typename ...Inputs>
void textBox(int x, int y, int xBoundary, const Inputs&... things) {
    std::string arr[sizeof...(things)] = {things...};
}
```

That gives no errors unless of course the user tries to pass something other than a string so I know that my error has something to do with making the array of template type. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to do in the end? Looks like an XY problem.

Comment: I explained that in the question @Holt

Comment: You explained what the function should do, not why you want to put everything in an array and what you want to do with it.

Comment: @Holt oh I apologize, I have a loop that converts all of the elements to a string and concatenates them to make one big string.

Comment: Typically, you cannot loop a tuple as easily as an array, so this is worth mentioning.

Comment: @Holt So I can't use a for loop and put each element through the stringstream? Also, how would I solve the error in my comment on the answer?

Comment: @Holt: in C++17 it's quite easy. C++14/11 require some more work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays need to contain elements of the same types - they are not heterogeneous data structures. In your case `Inputs` is a pack containing all the types of `things...` which is not expanded, which is why you are getting an error.

Use `std::tuple` instead, which is an heterogeneous container:

```
std::tuple<std::decay_t<Inputs>...> tuple{things...};
```

Or `std::make_tuple`:

```
auto tuple = std::make_tuple(things...);
```

---

In C++17, the template parameters might be omitted thanks to *class template argument deduction*:

```
std::tuple tuple{things...};
```

---

If you want to iterate over `things...`, it's best to not put them in a `std::tuple`. In C++17, you can use a *fold expression* to print all of them:

```
(std::cout << ... << things);
```

In C++11, you can define a pseudo-recursive variadic template:

```
template <typename T>
void print(const T& x)
{
     std::cout << x; 
}  

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
void print(const T& x, const Rest&... rest)
{
     print(x);
     print(rest...);
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I have always wondered what tuple was for. Where do i name the container? Do you name them like arrays?

Comment: Also, I get this error now. `error: 'std::tuple<char [9], std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > tuple' has incomplete type|`

Comment: @TNTFreaks: use `decay_t`, I updated my answer. What do you want to do with the tuple?

Comment: I explained it to Holt in the question comments. Its the 4th one.

Comment: @TNTFreaks: your question should be complete - edit it instead of asking people to jump around comments.

Comment: Ok I'll do that. Now I get this error `error: 'decay_t' is not a member of 'std'|` along with many others, when I remove the 'std::' it says decay_t isn't declared.

Comment: Use `typename std::decay<T>::type` in C++11. `decay_t` is C++14

Comment: It compiled thank you! Should I answer my own question with the code that I wrote based on yours?